# Error while calling an array resource with item "in"

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to load an array for my list preference. It is for height and so my values are 'in' for inches and 'cm' for centimeters. The preference list dialog crashes as soon as I try to open the dialog. When I change it to any string other than the item 'in' it works. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Edit:

Here is my array. I did not define it as string array.

> ```
> <array name="length_units">
>     <item>in</item>
>     <item>cm</item>
> </array>
> ```

Here is the stacktrace

```
> W/dalvikvm(18013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0x400259f8) E/AndroidRuntime(18013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013): java.lang.NullPointerException
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18013):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)
```

Comment: That sounds wild. Can you post the `<string-array>` that fails?

Comment: Edited my post with the array. I am using an <array> and not a <string-array>. I just tried it using <string-array> and it works fine. But I am still interested in know why it did not work in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, only `<string-array>` is supported by a `ListPreference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like CommonsWare said in the comments above, only  is supported by a ListPreference. Everything worked fine after I changed it to string-array.

I am just putting it here since he/she did not put it as an answer.